# D3js change ticks x and y axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3JS, and I've followed a tutorial on making a line graph at [CodeTuts](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-multi-line-chart-using-d3js--cms-22935).

The chart I want to make should show the amount of users per hour and category of device. Since I want to be able to see at which time people will switch to tablet or mobile instead of desktop, I've made three arrays.

The arrays are build like this:

```
var desktop = [
{
  'hour': 01,
  'users': 20
},
{
 'hour': 08,
 'users': 800
}
];
```

My graph looks like this now:
[image]
I would like to get to know how to set the xaxis values as:

```
00 , 01, 02, 03, 04 ,05, etc..
```

and The yaxis should have the focus on the lowest device categories (mobile and desktop, so the yaxis should be something like:

```
00, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 100, [maxvalue of users in desktop array]
```

So something like this it should be:
[image]

My  code:

```
function makeChart(desktopData,mobileData,tabletData){
    var WIDTH = 1200,
        HEIGHT = 300,
        MARGINS = {
                top:20,
            right:20,
            bottom:20,
            left:50
        }
    var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
        WIDTH = 1200,
        HEIGHT = 300,
        MARGINS = {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 20,
            left: 50
        },
        xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([00,23]),
        yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([00,100]),
        xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale),

        yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(yScale)
            .orient("left");

    vis.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class","axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    vis.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class","axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);

    var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d){
            return xScale(d.uur);
        })
        .y(function(d){
            return yScale(d.pageviews);
        });
    vis.append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', lineGen(desktopData))
        .attr('stroke','deepskyblue')
        .attr('stroke-width',2)
        .attr('fill','none');

    vis.append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', lineGen(mobileData))
        .attr('stroke','orange')
        .attr('stroke-width',2)
        .attr('fill','none');

    vis.append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', lineGen(tabletData))
        .attr('stroke','deeppink')
        .attr('stroke-width',2)
        .attr('fill','none');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To force ticks values on axis, you can use [ticks()](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#ticks) or [tickValues()](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#tickValues) (and even [tickFormat()](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#tickFormat) if you need to have a specific format displayed).

For instance:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .ticks(24); // Will display 24 ticks (for 24 hours on x axis)
```

For your `y axis`, you have to define the scale domain from 0 to the max value.
Instead of

```
yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom])
    .domain([00,100]), // All values above 100 will be out of the chart
```

Define the domain as follow (here using [d3.max()](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#max)):

```
var maxValue = d3.max(desktopArray, function(d){ return d.users });

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom])
    .domain([00, maxValue]),
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted, maybe I wasn't clear enough in my explanation. I don't want to show the values between 100 and maxvaluedesktop on the yAxis. So what I do want are these numbers on the yaxis: 0-100  [whitespace] maxvalue.